# Looking up starter [ERROR] Unable to find starter template for Sidemenu in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic7

My ionic version is 7
When I want to create a `Sidemenu` project, I encounter this error
And I don't know the solution

> This is my order , Error image:

```
ionic start appSideMenu Sidemenu
```

> This is the error I get

[image]

> Information that may be helpful

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct command to start an ionic side menu starter template is:

```
ionic start myApp sidemenu --capacitor
```

You can also refer to their official documentation here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/start#examples